# PowerPoint 2013 macro keeps file locked open after close command

Tags: vba, file, powerpoint, locked

I have a PowerPoint VBA function that opens presentations, copies slides into the active presentation, then closes the source presentation. It worked fine in 2010, but fails in 2013 (all on Windows 7) if it tries to open the same presentation more than once. It appears to me that after the presentation.close command is issued, the window is closed, but the file remains locked open until the VBA code exits. So if the code attempts to open that file again it returns the error:
"Method 'Open' of object 'Presentations' failed"

Here's a simplified form of the function I'm running that behaves the same way. I've had a colleague test this again in PowerPoint 2010 and it runs fine. I've also had a colleague test it under his 2013 to make sure it's not something with my particular installation.

```
Sub testopen()

Dim ppFile As Presentation
Dim i As Integer

Const fpath = "C:\test.pptx"

For i = 1 To 2
    Set ppFile = Application.Presentations.Open(fpath)
    ppFile.Close
    Set ppFile = Nothing
Next i

End Sub
```

The file test.pptx is just a blank presentation. In debug mode I can see the file opens and closes on the first loop, then on the second loop the open command fails and I can see in Windows explorer that the hidden temporary file still exists, indicating the file is still open, until I exit the VBA code. I also verified that the file is held open by adding in a function to check the file open status.

I've spent probably an hour googling this and cannot find any other descriptions of this problem. I'm sure I can implement a workaround but it's driving me crazy that I can't find any other reports of seemingly such a simple issue. Any suggestions are greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: This might occur if the file you're opening is in a folder that's synched ... ie, a dropbox folder or the like.

Comment: Hey Steve, I can repro this with any presentation in any folder with PPT 2013/2016. Looks like a bug.

Comment: The Presentations.Count still shows the file open with no Windows. If NewWindow is invoked, it will open the presentation window.

Comment: Thanks for confirming the issue, Shyam. I didn't know how to get the Window back open once it was closed so that gives me some other possible workaround options. Michael's answer below did resolve the issue, but since it requires an external VBS script it's not ideal.

Comment: Shyam: would you believe that it works fine here in PPT 2013.  FWIW, I'm shy about applying updates.  Maybe this is vindication?  ;-)  I've got PPT 15.0.4706.3001

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the file as Read Only resolved the issue. The open command is now:

```
Set ppFile = Application.Presentations.Open(fpath, msoTrue)
```

Also, saving the file before closing it resolved the issue. For that, add:

```
ppFile.Save
```

Interestingly, I had already tried setting the Saved property to True (ppFile.Saved = msoTrue), which does NOT work. Thanks to Michael for his suggestion on the VBS script. That does work and I had never run an external VBS script so I learned something new. In this case, I'd prefer to stick with a VBA solution.

Answer (score 0):

The Best way that I have achieved this is to simply create a VBS file and in the VBS file I call out the desired VBA code. It's little more hassle than to write the VBA code, but it's the solution that worked for me.

For example in the VBS file:

```
Dim args, objPP

Set args = WScript.Arguments
Set objPP = CreateObject("Powerpoint.Application")

objPP.Open "C:\path\to\file.ppx"
objPP.Visible = True

objPP.Run "The_Macro"

objPP.Save
objPP.Close(0)
objPP.Quit
```

Or better yet, have the entire code within the VBS file and have it copy the desired slides.

Hope this helps you achieve your result.

Comment: This did work for me but I'd consider it more of a workaround than a solution. I've asked around elsewhere too and this is the best suggestion I've received. I'll give it another day or two for others to respond and accept this as the solution if I can't come up with a strictly VBA-based solution. Thanks!